# React scrollIntoView() not working with ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref, js-scrollintoview

I have a react functional component defined as

```
    export const NavMenuHorizontal: React.FunctionComponent<NavMenuProps> = (
      props
    ) => {         
        const selectedItemRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
        React.useEffect(() => {
          selectedItemRef.current?.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            inline: "center",
          })
        });

        return (
              <List>
              {map(...) => (
                  <div ref={isActive ? selectedItemRef : undefined}>
                     some text 
                  </div>
               )}
              </List>
        );
    };
//isActive is true for only one item in the map
```

I am trying to make the selected list item scroll into view using a ref but unable to get the expected result. However, if I try to add debug breakpoint at the hook, it's working as expected and scrolling the element in viewport.

I also tried wrapping my scrollIntoView inside a setTimeout() which works but it scrolls it more than once and leads to a jarring effect.

Comment: you render a list of elements by map function. and each of this element is stored ind the same ref object ?? then only last of them is stored in this ref. Is this desired behavior ??

Comment: The ref is stored for only one item for which "isActive" is true. I'll update the question with this.

Comment: you've fixed this?